# Bridge edge loops not bridging to nearest vertex on adjacent edge loop?

Tags: edges, loop

I have two edge loops which I am trying to bridge.

[image]

The edge loops do not have an equal number of vertices. My assumption was that the Edge Loop Tool would just bridge to the nearest vertex.

[image]

Given that this doesn't appear to happen, would I be right in thinking that it cycles through the verts numerically and creates an edge each time? i.e select vert1a + vert1b then create edge,select vert2a + vert2b then create edge etc..

If so, is there a way around this either in the form of a smart bridge tool that will join to nearest corresponding vert on adjacent edge loop, or any other non-manual workaround?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload that part of your geometry? You can upload it at http://blend- 
exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part 
of your question. I have hard time reproducing your problem.

Comment: Thanks Leander, the link is here. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6635" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6635/) .

Comment: In the uploaded file there is only one example of the issue (bottom left), which I can correct manually. Unfortunately I have hundreds of these kind of loop pairs to bridge, some of which have no issue, others can have 4-5 verts bridging to other verts elsewhere on the corresponding edge loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to create face between the loops is to not treat the as edge loops.

1. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select two opposing edges and delete the <kbd>X</kbd> > *Edges*.
2. Select the opposite "end" vertices each and connect them with an edge <kbd>F</kbd>. You now have a single loop.
3. Selec this loop <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and fill it <kbd>F</kbd> with an n-gon.
4. Triangulate the ngon with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.
5. Select the four vertices which we disconnected at step 1 and fill the face <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leander, that's a great solution and works perfectly for me.